# Passing the table header in Hive transform

Tags: hadoop, header, hive, transform

I am creating a query in Hive to execute a R script. I am using transform function to pass the table. However when I receive the table in R it comes without the header. I know that I could create a variable and ask the user to insert the header manually but I do not wanna do it. 
I wanna do something automatically, I am considering two options:

1) Figure out a way to pass the table with the header included when using transform function

2) Save the header in a variable and pass it in transform (I have already tried it in different ways but instead of passing the result of the query it is passing the query string - as seen below)

Here is what I have:

```
--Name of the origin table
set source_table = categ_table_small;
--Number of clusters
set k = "5";
--Distance to be used in the model
set distance = "euclidean";
--Folder where the results of the model will be saved
set dir_tar = "/output_r";
--Name of the model used in the naming of the files
set model_name ="testeclara_small";
--Samples: integer, number of samples to be drawn from the dataset.
set n_samples = "10";
--sampsize: integer, number of observations in each sample. This formula is suggested by the package. sampsize<-min(nrow(x), 40 + 2 * k)
set sampsize = "50";

--Creating a matrix which will store the sample number and the group of each sample according to the algorithm
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  medoids_result AS SELECT * FROM categ_table_small;

--In the normal situation you don't have the output label, it means you just have 'x' and do not have 'y', so you need to add one extra column to receive
--the group of each observation
--ALTER TABLE medoids_result ADD COLUMNS (medoid INT);

set result_matrix = medoids_result;
set headerMatrix = show columns in categ_table_small;

--Trainning query
SET mapreduce.job.name = K medoids Clara- ${hiveconf:source_table};
SET mapreduce.job.reduces=1; 

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ${hiveconf:result_matrix} 
SELECT TRANSFORM ($begin(cols="${hiveconf:source_table}" delimiter= "," excludes="y")$column$end)
USING '/usr/bin/Rscript_10gb /programs_r/du8_dev_1.R ${hiveconf:k}${hiveconf:distance}${hiveconf:dir_tar}${hiveconf:model_name}${hiveconf:n_samples}${hiveconf:sampsize}${hiveconf:headerMatrix}'
AS 
(
$begin(table='${hiveconf:result_matrix}') $column$end
)
FROM
(SELECT *
FROM ${hiveconf:source_table}
DISTRIBUTE BY '1'
)t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line

```
hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true;select * from tablename;'
```

Where tablename refers to your  **table name**

If you want defaultly work for every table then you need to update the $HOME/.hiverc file with

`hive> set hive.cli.print.header=true;`

in the first line.